# Snowflake - Deleting a CTE because table has duplicate rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have `tableA` that has duplicate rows, I noticed that some columns are different but essentially I'm told that it doesn't matter and we just want to make sure there is a unique ID in each row.

I tried this in Snowflake but I read we can't use CTEs to delete, insert.. etc. So then how?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        _LOAD_DATETIME, 
        _LOAD_FILENAME, 
        _LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER, 
        ID, 
  CONTENT_CATEGORY,
  CREATED_TIME,
  DESCRIPTION,
  FROM_INFO,
  LENGTH,
  PERMALINK_URL,
  POST_VIEWS,
  PUBLISHED,
  TITLE,
  VIEWS,
  LOADED_DATE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                id, 
                FROM_INFO, 
                title
        ) row_num
     FROM 
        tableA)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Comment: The CTE is just an expression: it doesn't store anything so there's nothing to delete. Are you trying to delete rows from `tableA`? Or simply remove them from the results of your query?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - hi! I'm trying to delete any duplicate ids from tableA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative appraoch could be table recreation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tableA COPY GRANTS AS
SELECT *
FROM tableA
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  id, FROM_INFO,  title ORDER BY 1) = 1;
```

> *we just want to make sure there is a unique ID in each row.*

If id has to be unique then it should be partitioned only by `id` column. Before running the query CTaS it is advisable to check the part without CREATE TABLE part.

Comment: this worked but I had to add an 'order by id, from_info, title' inside the last parenthesis to get it to work. I'm not sure why though, do you know?

Comment: @KristiLuna  ROW_NUMBER requires a window specifiication. If any row per partition could be chosen then `ORDER BY` 1 will suffice.